# Google Map Lite mode in RecyclerView, OnMapReady Execute after list update

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-maps-android-api-2

I have recyclerView in which I try to show each item's location using google map lite mode.here is my implementation of RcyclerView adapter :

```
 public class ItemListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemListAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    List<ItemListModel> items = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;

    public ItemListAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cardview_item,parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v,context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            ItemListModel item = items.get(position);
            holder.setMapLocation(new LatLng(item.getLat(), item.getLon()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(MyViewHolder holder)
    {
        // Cleanup MapView here?
        if (holder.gMap != null)
        {
            holder.gMap.clear();
            holder.gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
        }
    }
    public void setItmes(List<ItemListModel> items){
        this.items.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnMapReadyCallback{

        GoogleMap gMap;
        MapView map;
        LatLng mMapLocation;
        Context context;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView,Context context) {
            super(itemView);

            map = (MapView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mapImageView);
            this.context = context;
            if (map != null)
            {
                map.onCreate(null);
                map.onResume();
                map.getMapAsync(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

            MapsInitializer.initialize(context);
            gMap = googleMap;
        }
        public void setMapLocation(LatLng mapLocation) {
            mMapLocation = mapLocation;

            if(gMap != null) {
                updateMapContents();
            }
        }
        protected void updateMapContents() {
            gMap.clear();
            gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mMapLocation));
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mMapLocation, 15f);
            gMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }
    }

}
```

the problem is in **myViewHolder** and in **onMapReady**, the **onMapReady** always execute after my list publishes and because of that the **gMap** is null during list update. and **setMapLocation** won't work as expected. as a ersult my MapView in Recyclerview Item is always empty.

where in my code i am doing wrong ?

Comment: make adapter after map ready then bind it to recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this issue was:

1. In onBindViewHolder(), set the `tag` of your ViewHolder's `map` to be the LatLng you want to show. (i.e. `map.tag = new LatLng(item.getLat(), item.getLon())`). You can choose to use other member variables inside your ViewHolder to temporarily hold the LatLng value, which you already did.
2. When the ViewHolder instance is created for the first time via onCreateViewHolder(), it initializes the map and onMapReady() is called AFTER onBindViewHolder(). Now in your `onMapReady()`, use the LatLng you just set in the `map.tag` or whatever variable you set from previous. In your case, just call `if (gMap != null) updateMapContents()`

This should solve your issue. I was inspired by this solution: 
https://github.com/androidcodegeeks/android-map_list/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/google/maplist

Let me know if it helps because I had the same issue.